# JSP request get parameter throws an exception

Tags: java, html, jsp, getparameter

I'm beginning JSP. I have the following HTML form.

```
<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type="text" name="sittingPlaces">
    <textarea name="invitees"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And the following java code.

```
if (request != null && request.getContentType() != null) {
    int sittingPlaces = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sittingPlaces"));
    String invites = request.getParameter("invitees");
}
```

I get an error at

```
int sittingPlaces = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sittingPlaces"));
```

Any idea why? Thanks loads.

Comment: **Exception:** org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /TP2.jsp at line 41

**root cause:** java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Comment: NumberFormatException: "Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format." which value are you assigning to sittingPlaces?

Comment: I tried leaving the text field empty, and tried writing a number in it as well.

Comment: You should validate that `request.getParameter("sittingPlaces")` is not null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if a string `request.getParameter("sittingPlaces")` is a valid number with the following method:

```
public boolean isInteger(String str) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false; // The string isn't a valid number
    }
    return true; // The string is a valid number
}
```

Or you can implement it inside your code:

```
if (request != null && request.getContentType() != null) {
    String sittingPlacesStr = request.getParameter("sittingPlaces");
    try {
        int sittingPlaces = Integer.parseInt(sittingPlacesStr);
        String invites = request.getParameter("invitees");
    } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) {
        // handle the error here
    }
}
```

The problem you are facing is that `NumberFormatException` is thrown because Java fails to convert your `String` to `Integer` because it does not represent a valid Integer. You should use a try-catch statement (just like in the example method above), to filter that Exception, as you have no control over the request coming from the client.

***Additionaly:***

You should also check if the `request.getParameter("sittingPlaces")` expression returns a valid string, and not a `null`:
String sittingPlaces = request.getParameter("sittingPlaces");

```
if (sittingPlaces != null {
    // Continue your code here
} else {
    // The client request did not provide the parameter "sittingPlaces"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. 

Another thing that I realized is that I am using post method and therefore couldn't get the parameters as they are searched in the body, not in the URL. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeBaillargeon The `request.getParameter(...)` method should always get the parameter from the request with the specified name, regardless of whether it is a **GET** method or a **POST** method. check if your HTML form is submitting the right parameters, with the right names.

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeBaillargeon Also, what do you mean "Couldn't get the parameters"? Do they return `null`, or trow an exception, or do anything else?

Comment: They are returning null. So this normal when using **POST**?

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeBaillargeon No, Try changing the method type from POST to GET, and repeat the operation again. I am sure that you will get the same result. Also, check what method (function) are you running the code in? `doGet()`, `doPost()`, or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

Check the value you are getting in sittingPlaces request parameter. Just try to print that on console using

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("sittingPlaces"));
```

and see the output.any trailing spaces, alphabet or special characters present.

In this case I believe you might be passing characters or trailing spaces.